# How to stay on same IP for days and weeks on tor browser?

Tags: tor

I want to create a secondary anonymous social media profile.
Since most social media websites can easily detect that it's the same person whos using two profiles so I want to avoid that & I want to use the tor browser to work on my second profile.

In order to achieve above, how do I keep the same IP address for weeks and every time log into the torr using an IP address in a specific city/ area?

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can edit the Tor Browser's `torrc` configuration file and use the [`ExitNodes`](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ExitNodes) configuration option to specify which exit node(s) you wish to use for your browsing session. You can pick the exit nodes using a country code, or a specific exit relay's identity fingerprint.

Selecting by city isn't an option unless you know a relay operator and where they are operating relays from, by country or autonomous system number is the best you can do to isolate where your traffic comes from. Depending on where you want the traffic to come from, you may have limited selections available, and there's no guarantee the same relay will always be fast or online at all.

Note that all Tor exits are known so no matter which exit you choose, the site you're browsing can easily identify your Tor usage, and using the same exit doesn't help with anonymity or making it harder to detect if you're the same person using another profile. In fact, it could be argued that using the same exit over a long period of time could reduce anonymity depending on how it's used. But if you're logging in to the same profile over time, then using the same or different exits may not make much difference.

One way to find suitable nodes is to use Tor's [relay search](https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#advanced) and use the Advanced mode as you will need to only select nodes with the "Exit" flag. Advanced search also lets you further reduce the list by selecting a country or AS.

Here are examples of what you might put in torrc:

```
# Only allow exit's through relays located in Russia
ExitNodes {RU}

# Only exit through a single node of your choosing
# The fingerprint here is displayed in relay search
ExitNodes ABCD1234CDEF5678ABCD1234CDEF5678ABCD1234
```

Comment: Thanks for this @drew010 I wonder, where do we find the fingerprint? As I am not sure what a relay search is :D

Comment: Another point is, the torrc file says it is cleaned each time? `# This file was generated by Tor; if you edit it, comments will not be preserved`

Comment: @JamieHutber : note that your citation says *"**comments** will not be preserved"* (not *"**content** will not be preserved"*)